# Get rid of unknow overflow CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to get rid of the overflow on the x axis and cannot find the reason for why its actually happening because its not very obvious. Every vw/width properties are set to 100. I'm pretty sure the .logout is causing this issue but I don't know what I should modify in order to fix it. Any help is appreciated!

```css
/* GLOBAL */
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: monospace;
}

header {
    position: relative;
}

/* MAIN */
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 40px;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}

.container {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

/* NAVBAR */
.nav {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #5f7866;
}
.navbar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 40%;
}

.items {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}

.item {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: black;
    font-weight: lighter;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

.item:hover {
    transition: all 0.1s ease;
    transform: scale(0.98);
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.links {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.logout {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border: 2px solid #49e31b;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    top: -10px;
    left: 600px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.logout:hover {
    background-color: #49e31b;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(0.98);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/index.css' %}">
    <title>{% block title %}  {% endblock title %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="nav">
        <h1 class="logo">Art Showcase</h1>
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul class="items">
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="links" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="links" href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
                </li>

                <li class="item">
                    <a class="links" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="links" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div>
                <a class="logout "href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
    {% block content %} 

    {% endblock content %}
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: with the overflow property u can get rid of the overflow but that means the menu items will not fit

Comment: Why are there so many position absolute?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole issue is the way you are using positioning and broken html structure (you forgot to close the navbar div after ul and opened another div for logout button. Use the code below for your reference :

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  font-family:monospace;
}
.nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns:auto auto auto;
  grid-gap : 30px;
  background: #5f7866;
  padding:10px;
}

.navbar .items li {
  display:inline-block;
  list-style:none;
  font-size:2em;
  margin-right:10px;
}

.navbar .items li a {
  color:#000;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.item:hover {
    transition: all 0.1s ease;
    transform: scale(0.98);
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.logoutDiv {
  text-align:right;
}

.logout {
    font-size: 2rem;
    border: 2px solid #49e31b;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.logout:hover {
    background-color: #49e31b;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(0.98);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/index.css' %}">
    <title>{% block title %}  {% endblock title %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header class="nav">
        <div>
          <h1 class="logo">Art Showcase</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul class="items">
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="links" href="{% url 'home' %}">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="links" href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a>
                </li>

                <li class="item">
                    <a class="links" href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a>
                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="links" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
           </div>
            <div class="logoutDiv">
                <a class="logout "href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
    {% block content %} 

    {% endblock content %}
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 100% instead of 100vw as it can be helpful ...

The problem is caused by your .logout class

A small fix to set your overflow

```
html , 
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
 }
```

Complete CSS fix

```
/*GLOBAL */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: monospace;
}

header {
  position: relative;
}

/* MAIN */


.container {
  background-color: black;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

/* NAVBAR */

.items {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.item {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-left: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: lighter;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.item:hover {
  transition: all 0.1s ease;
  transform: scale(0.98);
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.links {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.logout {
  font-size: 2rem;
  border: 2px solid #49e31b;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: right;
}

.logout:hover {
  background-color: #49e31b;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(0.98);
}

.nav {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #5f7866;
  padding-inline: 5%;
}

.navbar  , .nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.navbar > * {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
.nav > * {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```